# user_save() isn't saving the right password if it has an exclamation point

Tags: 7, users

I'm creating a user programatically using the user_save() function. If I use a password with an !, @, etc., the function seems to save the wrong password to the database because I can't use it to successfully log in. The user is otherwise created correctly. If I don't use a special character like the ones I listed, I'm able to login with the password fine.

There isn't too much relevant code to show...

```
$edit['pass'] = $_POST['password'];
...
$user = user_save($account,$edit);
```

I have verified that $_POST['password'] and then $edit['pass'] have the right values. Any idea what's going on, or even how to troubleshoot further?

Comment: How are you verifying that $_POST['password'] and $edit['pass'] have the right values?

Comment: By emailing them to myself using the PHP's mail() function. Very sophisticated stuff :)

Comment: well, just make sure that the DISPLAY of them is identical to their actual value, eg, if in email it shows !hello!, it might actually be !hello! or &#33;hello&#33; etc

Comment: I looked at the source code of the email and it is indeed a !, not the entity equivalent.

Comment: low hanging fruit gone, I've looked at the code and it doesn't do anything but hash up the password, and obviously !'s etc are allowable, so it must be something really odd going on somewhere :(

Comment: yeah, that's my feeling too. can't say i have a ton of hope at the moment...

Comment: I'd temporarily throw a watchdog() inside core's user_save() before it hashes the password to at least see what it is...maybe that will bring about the big Aha! moment.